# How to update one table with another, using third table as an index (SQLITE)

Tags: sqlite

I have three tables.

ONE contains:

```
ID1 VALUE
```

TWO contains:

```
ID2 NEWVALUE
```

THREE is kind of an index:

```
ID1 ID2
```

How can I update database ONE with data from database TWO, using THREE as an index?

From one to another, it works like this:

```
UPDATE ONE
    SET
      VALUE = (SELECT NEWVALUE FROM TWO WHERE ID2 = ONE.ID1)
```

So I probably just need a good select.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to only require a join between `TWO` and `THREE` and then a select from the result:

```
UPDATE ONE
   SET VALUE = (SELECT NEWVALUE
                  FROM TWO JOIN THREE ON (TWO.ID2 = THREE.ID2)
                 WHERE THREE.ID1 = ONE.ID1)
```

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you! I bashed my head for hours around this. I was not sure how to implement two successive WHERE operators, but I understand that I was actually missing a JOIN. Thank you again!